# Docker compose cannot RUN symfony database commands

Tags: mysql, docker, symfony, docker-compose, doctrine-orm

I'm developing a symfony 5.1 project with docker-compose and using GitLab registry.

I have a mysql:5.7 images for database, nginx:stable for server and php:7.4-fpm for PHP.

but when trying to compile it cannot `RUN bin/console doctrine:database:create --if-not-exists --no-interaction;` so it seems it can't connect to the database. Everything on the Dockerfile before creates database seems to work fine.

The error message I get is:

> Step 10/12 : RUN bin/console doctrine:database:create --if-not-exists --no-interaction;
> ---> Running in 8acb003982a3
>
> In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 93:
>
> An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 31:
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 27:
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 27:
>
> PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
>
> doctrine:database:create [-s|--shard SHARD] [-c|--connection [CONNECTION]] [--if-not-exists] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--]
>
> ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c bin/console doctrine:database:create --if-not-exists --no-interaction;' returned a non-zero code: 1

I have hardcoded in symfony .env file the database data like this: `DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@mysql:/mydb?serverVersion=5.7`

and in config/packages/doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    driver: 'pdo_mysql'
    url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

My mysql Dockerfile is as simple as `FROM mysql:5.7`

My ngingx Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:stable
COPY ./src/www/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY ./src/site.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

My php Dockerfile is:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    libmemcached-dev \
    libz-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    unzip \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libbz2-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    git \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql intl mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd

ENV COMPOSER_HOME /usr/share/nginx/html/.composer

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- \
    --install-dir=/usr/bin \
    --filename=composer

RUN mkdir -p $COMPOSER_HOME/cache

COPY ./src/www /usr/share/nginx/html
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html/smartlink
RUN COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer install --prefer-source --no-interaction
RUN bin/console doctrine:database:create --if-not-exists --no-interaction;
RUN bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction;
RUN bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force --no-interaction;
```

And the docker compose file is:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  
  mysql:
    container_name: symfony_mysql
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./infrastructure/docker/mysql/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '33060:3306'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'test'
    volumes:
      - ./src/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    env_file:
      - ./infrastructure/environments/development.env
    networks:
      - code-network

  php:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./infrastructure/docker/php/Dockerfile
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./src/www:/usr/share/nginx/html
    env_file:
      - ./infrastructure/environments/development.env
    restart: always
    networks:
      - code-network
    depends_on: 
      - mysql

  http:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./infrastructure/docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./src/www:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./src/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    env_file:
      - ./infrastructure/environments/development.env
    restart: always
    networks:
      - code-network
    depends_on:
      - php

networks:
  code-network:
    driver: bridge
```

When running on local if I need to run symfony database commands from terminal, I need to change the hardcoded database configuration of .env to `DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:33060/mydb?serverVersion=5.7`, with this config the database commands work from the terminal, but then symfony do not connect to the database. And with the other configuration symfony connects to the database but the terminal commands do not work.

It's like the three containers are not sharing the folder where symfony is correctly.

I've read a lot of tutorials to deploy symfony with this 3 containers, and I think I followed the tutorials correctly, but I can't make it work and I do not see anything wrong or different from the tutorials. Need some help with this error please.

PD: I add the conf nginx file, it the same I've read on the tutorials but I'm not sure if it's ok as each tutorial use a slightly different conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    # listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    # server_name localhost;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/smartlink/public;
    # index index.php index.html index.htm;
    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?:ht|git|svn) {
        deny all;
    }

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/smartlinkapp_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/smartlinkapp_access.log;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't try to communicate with the DB during the image build process. Do that after the container is build and up and running. And use the other service name as host name in the database URL.

Comment: @yivi I use the other service name as host name in the database URL as I say at the beginning, changing it to 127.0.0.1 is only a workaround to make the database commands on terminal. I added the commands during the build process to have the registry image done with the database. If not, when I deploy the registry images, there is no database and I get an error.

Comment: As I said in the other comment, you shouldn’t do DB things during image build. Also, in this case is simply not possible, since the DB is a service and the service is not up during image building. And the builder is not connected to the compose network.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make a decission. It's absolutly logical, that your web app couldn't connect inside the container when the host in the env file is defined as 127.0.0.1. You should use the container name, in this case just 'symfony_mysql'. You should provide an initial shell script which is executed inside the container and this is setting up your system with e.g bin/console doctrine:database:create, doctrine:fixtures:load and so on ...

You willl run into similiar effects when you're working with composer and you're trying to execute some commands on the host and some on your container. In that case you have to ensure, that your local system requirements meets the one of your docker project. E.g. any major php update could break your current workflow.

So set your project up, that every command inside the container is executed succesfully. Access your containers with 'docker exec' and work on them.

Also when your network connections inside the containers is working, you haven't much to modify to deploy your project with docker swarm or kubernetes.